# How can I set up a DMZ for Wireless Access?

Tags: proxy, wifi, dmz

My company uses Microsoft Windows Server 2003. Our internet connection goes through a proxy server across a WLAN to the main office.

I want to set up a wireless LAN in my local network whereby unmanaged users, given the SSID and key, can log in and access our internet services the easiest way possible with minimal configuration on each unmanaged PC in order to reduce the added workload for the administrators.

I was considered setting up a proxy or DMZ of some  sort, where the proxy sits between the inside network and the unmanaged network.

What do you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for but have you thought of Smoothwall Firewall for a good proxy?

Smoothwall is a 10-minute linux install and will do ANYTHING and everything.  It is very, very simple to setup and manage.

Here is the [site](http://www.smoothwall.org/)

and here is an [overview](http://www.skullbox.net/smoothwall.php)

If you just want simple wireless access, any wireless router would do.